# Recurrence relation of Hermite polynomials according to Holley and Stroock

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability

I am reading the appendix of the article of 1978 of Holley and Stroock  -- "Generalized Ornstein-Uhlenbeck processes and infinite Particle Branching Brownian Motions". The appendix is on Hermite Polynomials see below the first definitions:

[image]

I am trying to deduce relation $A.5$ from $A.3$ and $A.4$. I can't get there.

**Attempt:**
From $A.3$ we get
\begin{align}
xg_k   &= \frac{1}{2}g_{k+1} + k g_{k-1}\\ 
x^2g_k &= \frac{1}{2}xg_{k+1} + k xg_{k-1}\\
x^2g_k &= \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2}g_{k+2} + k g_{k}) + k (\frac{1}{2}g_{k} + k g_{k-2})\\
x^2g_k &= \frac{1}{4}g_{k+2} + k g_{k} + k^2 g_{k-2}
\end{align}
On the other hand, from $A.4$
\begin{align}
g'_k  &= -\frac{1}{2}g_{k+1} + k g_{k-1}\\ 
g''_k &= -\frac{1}{2}g'_{k+1} + k g'_{k-1}\\
g''_k &= -\frac{1}{2}(-\frac{1}{2}g_{k+2} + k g_{k}) + k (-\frac{1}{2}g_{k} + k g_{k-2})\\
g''_k &= \frac{1}{4}g_{k+2} - k g_{k} + k^2 g_{k-2}
\end{align}
Therefore 
$$- g_k'' + x^2g_k = 2k g_k $$ 
 and so I fail to arrive at $A.5$

where have I gone wrong?

**Remark:**
 The case $k = 0$ seems to be in accordance with the formula:

$$g_0 = e^{-x^2/2}$$
 $$g''_0 = (x^2 - 1)g_0 $$
$$-g_0'' + x^2 g_0 = g_0$$

The reason for this difference in my computations is because we cannot consider $g_{-1}$ properly in the recursion. With that caveat the formula becomes
$$-g_k'' + x^2g_k = 
\begin{cases}
2k g_k & k >0\\
g_0 & k = 0
\end{cases} $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just my mistake
\begin{align}
xg_k   &= \frac{1}{2}g_{k+1} + k g_{k-1}\\ 
x^2g_k &= \frac{1}{2}xg_{k+1} + k xg_{k-1}\\
x^2g_k &= \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2}g_{k+2} + (k+1) g_{k}) + k (\frac{1}{2}g_{k} + (k-1) g_{k-2})\\
x^2g_k &= \frac{1}{4}g_{k+2} + k + \frac{1}{2} g_{k} + k(k-1) g_{k-2}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
g'_k  &= -\frac{1}{2}g_{k+1} + k g_{k-1}\\ 
g''_k &= -\frac{1}{2}g'_{k+1} + k g'_{k-1}\\
g''_k &= -\frac{1}{2}(-\frac{1}{2}g_{k+2} + (k+1) g_{k}) + k (-\frac{1}{2}g_{k} + (k-1) g_{k-2})\\
g''_k &= \frac{1}{4}g_{k+2} - (k + \frac{1}{2}) g_{k} + k(k-1) g_{k-2}
\end{align}

therefore 
$$-g_k'' + x^2g_k = (2k + 1)g_k  $$